# How to delete auto-complete dictionary data on iOS 5.x?

Tags: ios, caching, autocomplete, keyboard

I am trying to turn off storing of auto-complete dictionary data in iPhone for my secure application. I want to prevent data leakage. I have found information that dictionaries are stored under a path: /var/mobile/Library/Keyboard. So the solution is easy. When application is going to foreground I cache all file under the path. When application did enter background I restore data from cache. So all new words added to dictionaries when my application was working aren't stored. It works great but only on iOS 6.x...

On iOS 5.x I learnt a dictionary a few new words then entered to background and then returned to application, auto-complete feature remembered the new words. I checked data under the path and it doesn't have these new words ! Furthermore in another application auto-complete feature doesn't "know" these new words ! When I relaunch my application the new words are unknown. That is mean there has to be another mechanism or local file that store these information only for working application.

How to permanently delete all auto-complete dictionary data from device with iOS 5.x ?

Comment: If your application needs to be that secure, turn off autocomplete for all your entry fields?

Comment: I want to disable auto-complete not only for secure fields but for all text fields. I don't want to set autocorrectionType for each of them because there are too many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't enable autocomplete on your secure fields. It's nothing but an annoyance anyway since things like usernames and passwords aren't suited for it. Documentation for this is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/autocorrectionType).

The autocomplete dictionary is, AFAIK, global to iOS, and your solution mentioned wont work on the device (it may work on the simulator) as your app won't have access to that folder.

Comment: I want to disable auto-complete not only for secure fields but for all text fields. I don't want to set autocorrectionType for each of them because there are too many of them.

My solution works great for iOS 6.x devices. In iOS 5.x there is a different behavior. It looks like device load data from dictionaries stored in hard disk and don't update these data when I update these dictionaries on hard disk. Does it make sense? Why another application doesn't know the words learnt in my app ?

Comment: I guarantee your solution is not working for ios6 devices, unless your device is jailbroken. Third party apps do not have access to that folder.